# Disabling CSRF on Spring generated project

Tags: spring-boot, csrf, swagger-ui, springfox

So I used Open API 3.0 and Swagger-Codegen to generate a Spring server. It seems CSRF is automatically enabled. I won't need CSRF as I will be using another method for auth, so I want to disable it.

I've tried the following:

- Upgrade Spring from 1.5.22-RELEASE to 1.5.9-RELEASE; Apparently in 1.5.2, CSRF is automatically enabled. This didn't work.
- Create a "WebSecurityConfig" class that extends WebSecurityConfiguererAdapter and overrides "configure". I followed some steps from previous posts with the same problem, unfortunately it still seems to be enabled.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

When I open Swagger UI, I can see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
springfox.js?v=2.9.2:1 No csrf token can be found
```

Am I missing anything? Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here - hope you find a solution! Even if I don't disable it. Enabling WebSecurity is enough to stop swagger-ui

Comment: Is it really SpringSecurity or could it be a Gson-Problem? In my case it was an incompatibility between Swagger + Gson...